# How is gradient magnetic field generated in MRI scanner, considering 0 divergence

Tags: magnetic-fields, electrical-engineering

During the phase and frequency encoding process of MRI scanner, gradient field with a gradient is applied along the direction to change kx and ky of spins at different spatial location.
I am confused how is this gradient achieved considering the magnetic field has 0 divergence.

Take ky as phase encoding direction and kx as frequency encoding direction. I think a possible explanation is that the frequence encoding gradient also have none zero components along phase encoding direction ky. Then the previous encoded ky will also be changed, and some algorithm should be applied to encoding the ky with both phase and frequency encoding gradient. However, this is contradict to what I have learned before (https://mriquestions.com/what-is-phase-encoding.html), which says ky is only changed with phase encoding pulse.

Answer (score 1):

Divergence is not the same thing as gradient, although as you know it is calculated by what can be thought of symbolically as the dot product of the gradient vector with the vector field in question.

When something has "0 gradient" it is uniform in space. It does not change in any direction. You will usually see the gradient of scalars, which will be a vector, however, you *can* find the gradient of a vector (such as the magnetic field), and this will be a second order tensor.

Just because something has 0 divergence does not mean it is uniform in space. There are all sorts of vector fields that have zero divergence but vary in space. Any fluid flow for an incompressible fluid (i.e. a water flow field) will have this property.

I would recommend reading any text on vector calculus. It sounds like you are still working on these ideas a bit.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think the frequency/phase encoding field here is along a single direction (frequency/phase encoding direction). Then during frequency encoding (set it as direction $\vect{i}$), the divergence for a small voxel at loaction $x$ is simply $\vec{i}\cdot(B_{x+\eps}\vec{i} - B_{x-\eps}\vec{i})$, which is none zero. Can you point out the error in my calculation?

Comment: I'm not even sure what you typed because the markup code has errors, however, that does not look like a divergence to me. Divergence must be of the form $\nabla \cdot \vec{B}$. This requires knowing the magnetic field, $\vec{B}$, which whatever you said in your comment is not enough for me to know. However, assuming you have some expression for the field as a function of space, you can take the three derivatives and add them, as is done for a divergence.

Comment: I recently find it out. I mistook the direction of gradient of magnetic filed as the same as the direction of magnetic field. I thought the magnetic field $B_x(x)$ is changing along $x$. In fact, the case is $B_z(x)$ is changing along $x$.

Comment: Yes, like I said, you *can* take a gradient of a vector field, but it will be a second order tensor. So you can have the gradient of the x component be along the z direction or whatever.